# Add css style to textbox

Tags: css

Here I have created css effect for textbox. But it does not effect.

What wrong please correct.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgTy2/2/)

css is as below:

```
in1
{
    border-radius: .2em;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;

    -webkit-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
}

in1:focus
{
    border-color: rgba(1, 168, 255, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px     rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
}
```

Comment: Fiddle is not linked correctly

Comment: Add correct fiddle link pls.

Comment: for class you mention . for id you mention #

Answer (score 4):

You just need to put a full stop before your class names in your css e.g.

```
.in1 { }
```

Comment: Thanks. But When I used same css on my local system, it does not show me same color effect as on fiddle.

Comment: Perhaps something else is overriding the style? If you inspect it using Firebug can you see the styles being applied?

Comment: May be. Firebug shows the style `#text.style1`. style1 is the name of the class.

Comment: That's not the name of your class in your original post though? I think you need to post more of your html/css.

Answer (score 2):

*Class selectors* are prefixed with a `.`. Here you're just using `in1` which is an *element selector*. This attempts to select an element named "in1" (`<in1 ... />`).

Simply change your selectors to:

```css
.in1 {
    ...
}
```

...and:

```
.in1:focus {
    ...
}
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SgTy2/3/).

You can read more about CSS selectors in the official W3 documentation available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). From the same document's [Class Selector section](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html):

> `E.warning` - an `E` element whose class is "warning" (the document language specifies how class is determined).

Answer (score 2):

without looking at your fiddle i'm guessing you're using classes.

try adding a "." to the start of your css, so: `.in1`

Answer (score 1):

You must follow this, a class selector is a name preceded by a full stop (“.”) and an ID selector is a name preceded by a hash character (“#”).

> instead of in1{} put .in1{}